# SQL Conditional Where Statement with AND logic in different code and OR logic in same code

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, ssms, where-clause

I have a table say `Person` with columns like

```
Id, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, PinCode
```

I will be querying this table from a stored procedure and my request will have input as Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4 say

Code1 will have `1|8787909000|8787909022` and Code2 will have `2|ABC|XYZ` and so on

- 1 -> Indicates code and parameters for Code1
- 2 -> Indicates code and parameters for Code2

Rules:

- When Code1 alone is passed I need to query table with PhoneNumber column alone
- When Code2 alone is passed I need to query table with AddressLine1 column alone
- When Code3 alone is passed I need to query table with AddressLine2 column alone
- When Code4 alone is passed I need to query table with PinCode column alone

But say when Code1 and Code2 is passed I need to query PhoneNumber and AddressLine1 and similarly for other columns too.

Also when 2 phone numbers are passed in the request I need to query PhoneNumber column with OR condition

When same code is passed in the request, it should be logical OR and when different logical code is present it should be logical AND

For example:

- Code1 - PhoneNumber1 OR PhoneNumber2
- Code2 - AddressLine1
- (PhoneNumber1 OR PhoneNumber2) AND AddressLine1

**i.e (Code1 AND Code2)**

Can some please share the logic for this?

Comment: This is why JSON was invented.  Could you pass the parameters as a JSON document?

Comment: [This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) may help.

Comment: If the parameters all get pass in as a JSON document we can open it and any missing fields are interpreted as null rows.  The we have 5 queries which amount to a large coalesce statement because they each join to the flattened JSON differently.